# Socket between submit and execute hosts closed unexpectedly

Tags: sockets, sas, cluster-computing, winscp

I am attempting to run a `SAS` file on a cluster.  The contents of the `SAS` file `myprogram.sas` are shown below:

```
data a;
   input myvar1;
   myvar2 = myvar1 + 100 ;
   datalines;
       0
       1
       2
       3
       4
       5
;
proc print;
run;
```

I create a `Condor` file to execute the `SAS` file on the cluster.  The contents of the `Condor` file `mycondorcode.condor` are shown below, except that I have altered the email address:

```
####################
#
# Submit SAS code to Condor cluster
#
# Submit this to run on the cluster with condor_submit THIS-FILENAME.condor
#
####################

UNIVERSE                = vanilla
NOTIFICATION            = Complete
NOTIFY_USER             = mark.miller@zzz.org

REQUIREMENTS            = (OpSys == "LINUX" && HAS_SAS )
GETENV                  = TRUE

EXECUTABLE              = /usr/local/bin/sas
ARGUMENTS               = -nodms -noterminal
INPUT                   = myprogram.sas
OUTPUT                  = $(INPUT).out
ERROR                   = $(INPUT).err
LOG                     = $(INPUT).log

QUEUE
```

I copy the `SAS` and `Condor` files to the cluster using an application called `WinSCP.exe` which I guess converts the `SAS` file to a format the cluster can understand, I guess like a `dos2unix` command.

Then I submit the `SAS` file to the cluster using `PuTTY` by typing:

```
condor_submit mycondorcode.condor
```

When I type:

```
condor_q
```

I see:

```
 ID      OWNER            SUBMITTED     RUN_TIME ST PRI SIZE CMD
58683.0   markm          11/24 14:41   0+00:00:00 I  0   0.0  sas -nodms -noterm
```

Status (`ST`) remains `I` no matter how long I wait.

I can see a text file in my directory called `myprogram.sas` which contains the following (except that I have altered the email address and altered the number that looks like it could be an IP address):

```
000 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:41:55 Job submitted from host: <14.4.104.1:42259>
...
022 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:42:56 Job disconnected, attempting to reconnect
    Socket between submit and execute hosts closed unexpectedly
    Trying to reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org <14.4.104.23:50176>
...
024 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:42:56 Job reconnection failed
    Job not found at execution machine
    Can not reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org, rescheduling job
...
022 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:43:56 Job disconnected, attempting to reconnect
    Socket between submit and execute hosts closed unexpectedly
    Trying to reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org <14.4.104.23:50176>
...
024 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:43:56 Job reconnection failed
    Job not found at execution machine
    Can not reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org, rescheduling job
...
022 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:44:56 Job disconnected, attempting to reconnect
    Socket between submit and execute hosts closed unexpectedly
    Trying to reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org <14.4.104.23:50176>
...
024 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:44:56 Job reconnection failed
    Job not found at execution machine
    Can not reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org, rescheduling job
...
022 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:45:57 Job disconnected, attempting to reconnect
    Socket between submit and execute hosts closed unexpectedly
    Trying to reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org <14.4.104.23:50176>
...
024 (58683.000.000) 11/24 14:45:57 Job reconnection failed
    Job not found at execution machine
    Can not reconnect to slot1@node13.hpc.zzz.org, rescheduling job
...
```

I have never successfully used this cluster, but have run `R` on a different cluster.  I know virtually nothing more about the current cluster.  Based on what I have provided above does it appear that I am doing something incorrectly, or does it appear that there is a connection problem which must be addressed by the IT department who operates the cluster?

Thank you for any suggestions I might try to resolve this problem from my Windows desktop side while being almost entirely unfamiliar with `Unix` or `clusters` in general.  Perhaps I am doing something incorrectly with `WinSCP.exe`.  Perhaps instead of using `WinSCP` I might try using `dos2unix`?

Comment: WinSCP is a file transfer software; you can use it to FTP, sFTP, or do all sorts of other things.  If you instruct it to use Text mode, it will convert the CRLF to LF or back (if going from Windows to *nix) just like almost any other FTP program.  You certainly could inspect the lines to verify this is happening.  What I'd check first is that the `myprogram.sas` is properly pathed - I would always explicitly path it (`/usr/doc/mysas/myprogram.sas`) at least during testing.

Comment: I'd also say the same thing applies to the condor script, though I know nothing about condor; but when the error is effectively 'file not found', full paths are often the answer.

Comment: WinSCP by default uses binary transfer mode. You need to [explicitly select text/ascii mode](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode), if you need it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Thank you.  I think someone did that for me last week, but I am still seeing the error above.  I failed to mention that in my post.  Of course, perhaps the change the person made was not correct.  Is there a way I can check whether the file is in the correct format after being transferred to the cluster?

Comment: The IT person was able to solve the problem and the socket error was eliminated.  However, I do not know what the IT person did, so I cannot provide an answer.  However, that alone was not enough for the SAS file to run.  I still had to change the format of the SAS file to Unix script using Notepad++ after moving the SAS file to the cluster.  Then I had to change the line: `INPUT                   = myprogram.sas` to: `INPUT                   = myprogram.sh` in the Condor file.  Do not convert the Condor file to Unix Script format.

Comment: My IT person just told me that the approach described in my last comment is not a good solution.  He told me that you want to keep sas files as having the .sas extension. He said to change the extension back to .sas and modify the condor file accordingly.  He also said that to save as UNIX format open the file you want to convert, then choose the edit menu and then "EOL conversion" then choose the appropriate conversion for whether you're converting something from UNIX->Win or Win->UNIX.